# Counting the most amount of zeros in a row in a number | Python

Tags: python

I want to create a function that asks for a number and then sees the most amount of zeros in a row and returns its value (ex: 5400687000360045 -> 3  | 03500400004605605600 -> 4).
So far this is all I got but it isn't working:

```
def zeros():
    num = input('Write a number: ')
    row = 0
    result = 0
    for i in num:
        if i == '0':
            while i == '0':
                row += 1
                if row > result:
                    result = row
    return result
```

What's  wrong?

EDIT:
This is what the desired output should be:

```
zeros()
Write a number: 03500400004605605600
4
```

My current output is nothing, meaning it's not returning anything

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? What is your current output, and what is the desired output? Also, the code as written will not run, check your indentation levels.

Comment: I edited to explain that better but basically I have no current output and the output should be the biggest amount of zeros in a row of the number that you write

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Because you are not printing anything... Try `print(zeros())`...

Comment: Also, small issue, you have an infinite loop with that `while`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
def zeros():
    num = input('Write a number: ')
    row = 0
    count = 0
    for i in num:
        if i == '0':
            count += 1
        else:
            row = max(row, count)
            count = 0
    row = max(row, count)
    return row
```

Your code is getting stuck in an infinite loop in inner while

Answer (score 1):

To do it your way, you just need to keep track of whether the number is a 0 or not (i.e. to know if it is a row of zeros or if you need to restart the count). Something like this would work:

```
def zeros():    
    num = input('Write a number: ')
    row = 0
    result = 0
    for i in num:
        if i != '0':
            row = 0
        else:
            row += 1
            if row > result:
                result = row
    return result
```

Output is as you would expect.

If you know regex, you could achieve this with much less code using:

```
import re

def zeros():    
    num = input('Write a number: ')
    result = max(map(len, re.findall(r'0+', num)))
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful to you..? regex (Regular expression operations) is a very handy tool which could make your life easier. Please have look at [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re
def zeros():
    num = input('Write a number: ') 
    return max(re.findall("(0+0)*", (num)))
```

output : `000`

---

```
def zeros():
    num = input('Write a number: ') 
    return len(max(re.findall("(0+0)*", (num))))
```

output : `3`

Comment: you don't need the `re.compile` step - just use `re.findall`

Comment: @jsbueno,Yes you are correct,  thanks for the ammendment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

```
num = input()

countOfZeros = 0
for i in range(len(num)-1):
    curr = 0
    if num[i] == num[i+1]:
       curr = 0
       if curr > countOfZeros:
           countOfZeros = curr
       else:

           countOfZeros += 1
print(countOfZeros - 1 )
```